# Group by using a key

Tags: manipulate, dataset

I have a dataset which looks like this:

[image: Dataset]

I want to create another dataset such that I get the count of A1flag for each userId, i.e., 5311->2, 5313->2.

I tried the following code

`GroupBy[FEflag[Select[#A1flag == 1 &], {"userId", "A1flag"}], "userId",Length]`

but, with this I lose the names of columns.

Anyone has a better suggestion?

Comment: Consider adding a small test dataset to your question so we don't have to come up with our own :)

Comment: A test dataset can be generated by `FEflag = AssociationThread[{"userId", "A1flag"}, #] & /@ {{5311, 1}, {5311, 1}, {5313, 1}, {5313, 1}, {5313, 1}} // Dataset`

Comment: `Values@GroupBy[FEflag[Select[#A1flag == 1 &], All], "userId", Total]` should do it, but it will only work when the value of `A1flag` is 1, or it will count weird.

Comment: Ok. I shall follow this from the next time. I wasn't aware of how to add datasets to the posts

Comment: @CarlLange A1flag has only 1 and 0. But the code you shared doesn't work

Comment: @Maria don't wait for the next time, please update the question with a minimal example and the expected result so that everything is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
FEflag = AssociationThread[{"userId", "A1flag"}, #] & /@
  {{5311, 1}, {5311, 1}, {5313, 1}, {5313, 1}, {5313, 1}, {5313, 0}} // Dataset
```

[image]

```
GroupBy[FEflag, First -> Last, Total]
```

[image]

The same result can be achieved more robustly with

```
GroupBy[FEflag, Key["userId"] -> Key["A1flag"], Total]
```

[image]

which makes fewer assumptions about the ordering of the columns.

I don't know a pretty way of keeping the name of the first column, but the following works by reconstructing a new `Dataset` from the results of `GroupBy`:

```
KeyValueMap[<|"userId" -> #1, "sum" -> #2|> &, 
  GroupBy[FEflag, Key["userId"] -> Key["A1flag"], Total]]
```

[image]

## edit

Following @VictorK. 's solution, the above query can be simplified a bit:

```
KeyValueMap[<|"userId" -> #1, "sum" -> #2|> &,
  FEflag[GroupBy["userId"], Total, "A1flag"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works, but it removes the column names. I want to keep userId for the first column and rename the new count column with something else.

Comment: Thanks, it works :)

Comment: I just cleaned it up a bit, the new version is better. Still a hack though.

Comment: You can keep the column name by using `Part` with a list: `GroupBy[FEflag, First -> Function[#[[{"A1flag"}]]], Total]`

Comment: @SjoerdSmit do you know how to keep the `userId` as well, without doing a `Dataset@KeyValueMap` on the result of `GroupBy`?

Comment: Well, `GroupBy` always returns an association, so you'll always need to do some extra step to turn it into a list of associations. There is also the function `GatherBy`, which returns a list, but that's not very easy to use in this situation. Or you do `GroupBy[FEflag, Function[#[[{"userId"}]]] -> Function[#[[{"A1flag"}]]], Total]` and just accept that you get an association with associations for keys.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to repeat the "userId" field in the [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy) RHS, and then use [`Values`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Values):

```
Values @ FEflag[
    GroupBy["userId"],
    <|"userId" -> "userId" @* First, "A1flag" -> Total @* Lookup["A1flag"]|>
]
```

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned the most straightforward solution that is mentioned on [`Dataset` help page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html):

```
FEflag[GroupBy["userId"], Length, "A1flag"]
```

[image]

Comment: probably because `<|5311 -> 2, 5313 -> 4|>` is not a desired result.

Comment: indeed; I completely missed part of the requirement.